# Undefined reference to a function in another library

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile an object code with a reference to one lib. This is the code of libexample.c:

```
#include "libexample.h"
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

timer_t sched;
struct itimerspec timer = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};

void init() {
    struct sigaction sa;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

    timer_create(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, NULL, &sched);
    timer_settime(sched, TIMER_ABSTIME, &timer, NULL);
}
```

And the simple code of a example program:

```
#include "libexample.h"

int main() {
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

I use this to compile:

```
gcc libexample.c -c -lrt -o libexample.o
gcc example.c -lrt ibexample.o -o example
```

And I get this when I'm trying to compile with the second line:

```
./libexample.so: undefined reference to `timer_create'
./libexample.so: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, about the changes, but I get the problem even with -lrt.

Comment: Ok, it was only the order of the params to gcc.
Putting -lrt to the end of the line, resolves the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `man timer_create` command [explains](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) you:

```
NAME
   timer_create - create a POSIX per-process timer

SYNOPSIS
   #include <signal.h>
   #include <time.h>

   int timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent *sevp,
                    timer_t *timerid);

   Link with -lrt.
```

So you should, as documentation says, link with `-lrt`.

So use

```
 gcc libexample.c -fPIC -shared -o libexample.so -lrt
```

to produce your `libexample.so`.

As  [undur_gongor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908515/undur-gongor) commented, you need to put the libraries in good order after all the rest (the usual order for `gcc` arguments is source files, object files, libraries in dependency order)  in `gcc` or `ld` commands (and that is documented in `ld` documentation, and in `gcc` ones). So `-lrt` should go last.

And learn to read man pages.

Comment: There is a `-lrt` in the question's command-lines. It is the order of the options which matters.

Comment: @undur_gongor in the first version of the question `-lrt` was even not present.

Comment: @ouah: Yes, apparently. Unfortunately quick edits after creating a question are not documented as such.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-lrt` to your link command. `timer_create` and `timer_settime` are not part of the C Standard library.

```
gcc -fPIC -shared libexample.c -lrt -o libexample.so
gcc -L. example.c -lexample -o example
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to link in the library that defines timer_create and timer_settime -- you need to add `-lrt` to your `gcc` command.

(source: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cmake, make sure you include the libraries using `target_link_libraries()`. For e.g., timer functions like `timer_create()` you need `"rt"` and for `pthread` you need `"pthread"` added using `target_link_libraries()`.